# HowTo autostart app to All Users installed with Basic Project (InstallShield 2010)?

Tags: autostart, installshield-2010

**Question**: I have a *InstallShield 2010* installed. I want to create a *Basic Project*, that would be able to install my simple application (single `.exe` file) to `ALLUSERS` on the host and also I need is to autostart application on every users log on. What I have to do? What parameters I need to realize my plan?

PS. I`m not planning to create additional dialog in installer. This things must be executed in "invisible mode".

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer is to start you application from `Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run` section in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

Answer (score 0):

So add a shortcut that installs to the Startup folder, or, if you're feeling more evil, a Run key registry entry. The purpose of the dialog is not to do the actual deed, but to give the customer a chance to opt in or out of behavior he may not want. Since it will have to communicate the choice by setting a public property, the silent installation case can be controlled by passing that property on the command line.